Number of jumps to reach the end (with updates)
We are given N squares number 0 to N - 1. Each square has target jump square J[i] (which must be at a larger index). At square i, you can only jump to square J[i]. If J[i] is past the last square, then you are done.
We know all J[i] at the start, then we have Q queries. if query is update, it changes J[i] for a specific i (still satisfies J[i] > i). other type of query ask for how many jumps it takes starting from a given square to go past the last square (N-1).
Constraints:
1 <= N, Q <= 100,000
i + 1 <= J[i] <= 1,000,000

Example:
Jump squares: 
[1, 3, 3, 5]
Get answer fro square 1: 1 -> 3 -> 5 [past end] (2 jumps)
Update square 2's jump square (J[2]) to 4
Get answer for square 2: 2->4 [past end] (1 jump)

I tried to use dp (dynamic programming) to store # of jumps from each square, but updates make my solution slow down too much since I have to update dp answer for possibly all the squares.
static int[] dp;

static int getjump(int square, int[] jumpSquares) {
    if (square >= dp.length) return 0; // past end
    if (dp[square] != -1) return dp[square]; // already calc
    return dp[square] = 1 + getjump(jumpSquares[square], jumpSquares); // do one jump and check
}

static List<Integer> solve(int n, int[] jumpSquares, int[][] queries) {
    dp = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) dp[i] = -1;
    List<Integer> answers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int[] qq : queries) {
        if (qq.length == 1) {
             answers.add(getjump(qq[0], jumpSquares));
        } else { // update
             jumpSquares[qq[0]] = qq[1];
             for (int i = 0; i <= qq[0]; i++) dp[i] = -1; 
             // reset answers that might depend on updated square (qq[0])
        }
    }
    return answers;
}

how do I solve this more efficiently (better than O(N*Q))?

Firstly, it’d be beneficial to solve the problem asking for the minimum number of jumps. If there are updates, those can be dealt with separately and not related to the first query. Secondly, I believe you’ve an incorrect understand of J[i]. For any i, J[i] should be the farthest square you can jump to, but any of the intermediate squares should be reachable also. That’s the only thing that makes sense. Now for the fewest jumps, choose the next square such that the sum of the distance from the current square and the maximum distance you can jump to from the next square is maximum.

You can find plenty of solutions for this problem on LeetCode.   https://leetcode.com/problems/jump-game-ii/

@AbhijitSarkar no, please don't assume I'm stupid. this is a completely different problem. J[i] is the ONLY square you can go to from square i. we do NOT look for minimum # of jumps, there is only way to jump from square i to past the end, but the problem is how many jumps that takes. That other problem you linked to is way easier, especially n is only 10,000 so O(n^2) can pass.

I'm sorry for confusion on title, edited it

I'm not assuming anything here. I'm saying if you can jump to a maximum of 6 feet, then you can also jump to any distance less than 6 feet, that's just how physics works, and no programming site can change that.

@AbhijitSarkar but nobody said anything about being able to jump a maximum of some distance. its clearly written that J[i] is the only square you can jump to (not max jump distance or anything related to that). this is just how the problem is formulated, i just called it jumps, but if you dislike that you can call it anything you want. you are actually assuming that jumping must be physical jumping and the squares are in a line,  when none of that needs to be true. we shouldn't assume anything not in the problem statement

_nobody said anything about being able to jump a maximum of some distance" - You did, "At square i, you can only jump to square J[i]. If you don't mean jumping, don't say jumping, use another word, it's not that hard.

@AbhijitSarkar its not that deep . I wrote jump but certainly didn't write jump a max of some distance. it was clearly written as "only jump to square J[i]", not sure what other way to read that.

To be clear here, Abhjiit's ideas and understanding are wildly off here. Adjiit: No, the problem cannot be separated into two parts; the simple ways to make the jump thing faster actually make the 'process updates' thing slower. The problem even without the update thing is already interesting. Imagine J[i] = i+1 for all J, then to 'walk' it takes 100,000 steps. Do that for 100,000 queries and you're running 10 billion steps, quite inefficient.

Abjiit's link goes to the jump square game without the update thing, and is thus not relevant to the question.

@AbhijitSarkar Updates really cannot be considered completely separately from queries if one wants both to be efficient.

I'm not sure this is easily solvable in a way that is algorithmically less complicated than O(n*q). We're going to have to find a hard way.
Visualizing the problem, each square has an arrow going to some other square. just following each arrow is too slow (can take up to 100k 'arrow follows' just to deal with a single query), but memoizing the answer means it takes potentially 100k steps just to update / invalidate the memoizations, which is also too slow.
We can make one query fast, but that makes the other query slow.
We need something extra to make this doable; the basic rules seem to doom us to an O(n*q) algorithm.
The rule that all jumps go forward is the key extra helper fact. We can chop the problem up into pieces: Instead of memoizing how many steps it takes to 'reach the end', memoize how many steps it takes to get to the next segment, where we define each segment to e.g. be 316 squares. In other words, we chop up the square ids into 317 sections, each 316 squares large. Segment 0 is 0-315, segment 1 is 316-631, etcetera (316 is chosen because it's SQRT(100_000)).
In other words, instead of memoizing "It takes 20 steps to get from square 58 to the end", e.g. memoization[58] = 20, you instead memoize for square 58 "it takes 8 steps to get to square 325", where 325 is the first square in the next segment you 'hit' when you start walking from 58. That does mean you now need to store 2 numbers (8, and 325), but if you really want to optimize, 100_000 * 317 is only 31600000 and fits in an int (in other words, you can compress 'square I end up at' and 'amount of steps this will take' into a single 4-byte int number if you must).
With this system in place, figuring out the 'how many steps does it take to get to the end' query takes O(sqrt(n)) steps, not O(n) steps. You still walk the tree as normal but every step is guaranteed to advance you by at least 1 segment, and there are only 317 segments, so the worst case scenario is just 317 (square root of n).
An update query also only takes sqrt(n) steps at most. Any jumpsquares that lead to the updated square do not need to be updated if the 'source' square is in a lower segment. After all, you are guaranteed that the memoized jump ends in the updated square (or earlier) which is fine. The only squares that might need their memoizations updated are any squares in the same segment that jump through the updated square. Figuring this out is similarly bounded by O(sqrt(n)) because you never have to check more than 316 source squares. To efficiently check, walk backwards, or memoize a list of squares that go through this square (this list can contain at most 316 entries; creating a 316-size array for each square is 126MB; large, but doable). I'll leave as an exercise to the reader how to do this efficiently.
You end up with an algorithm that is O(sqrt(n)*q); I have no proof but that strikes me as the most efficient available; surely it should be enough. In general 100_000 * sqrt(100_000) = 31 million, and anything 'less than 1 billion' tends to run in at most a handful of seconds.

Would this be Mo’s algorithm?

@גלעדברקן This general concept is square root decomposition, which Mo's algorithm is considered a more specific case of. I'm surprised you would know of Mo's (which is more rarely used) but not the more general form.

@Unmitigated ah, thanks for explaining!

This can be solved by square root decomposition. Split the array into blocks of size approximately √N and for each square, compute the number of jumps to go past the end of its block as well as the destination square of the first jump that leaves the block. These values can be calculated in O(N) at the start by iterating backwards over the array.
To answer a query, we can keep following these block-spanning jumps until we reach the end, which goes through at most O(√N) blocks (with a block size of about √N, there will also be around √N blocks).
To perform a point update of the jump square, it is only necessary to update the elements in the same block that are not at a higher index, taking time proportional the size of the block, which is O(√N).
The overall time complexity is O(Q√N).
Sample implementation:
static List<Integer> solve(int n, int[] jumpSquares, int[][] queries) {
    int blockSize = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
    int[] next = new int[n], jumpsToNext = new int[n];
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (jumpSquares[i] < n && i / blockSize == jumpSquares[i] / blockSize) {
            next[i] = next[jumpSquares[i]];
            jumpsToNext[i] = 1 + jumpsToNext[jumpSquares[i]];
        } else {
            next[i] = jumpSquares[i];
            jumpsToNext[i] = 1;
        }
    var res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (var query : queries) {
        if (query.length == 1) {
            int jumps = 0;
            for (int curr = query[0]; curr < n; curr = next[curr])
                jumps += jumpsToNext[curr];
            res.add(jumps);
        } else {
            jumpSquares[query[0]] = query[1];
            for (int i = query[0]; i >= query[0] / blockSize * blockSize; i--)
                if (jumpSquares[i] < n && i / blockSize == jumpSquares[i] / blockSize) {
                    next[i] = next[jumpSquares[i]];
                    jumpsToNext[i] = 1 + jumpsToNext[jumpSquares[i]];
                } else {
                    next[i] = jumpSquares[i];
                    jumpsToNext[i] = 1;
                }
        }
    }
    return res;
}

